# how to insert special character in mysql via php and display on html page

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

how to insert special characters into a database(MySQL) like

`Registered symbol ( ® )` OR
`Copyright sign ( © )` OR
`Trade Mark sign ( ™ )`

Also I want to display as original on the html page.

What I have to do in both side (front end and back end), please elaborate

Which function is more effective?

#### Method 1:

```
$_GET = array_map('trim', $_GET);
$_POST = array_map('trim', $_POST);
 
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
  $_GET = array_map('stripslashes', $_GET);
  $_POST = array_map('stripslashes', $_POST);  
  
  $_GET = array_map('strip_tags', $_GET);
  $_POST = array_map('strip_tags', $_POST);  
 }
 else{
  $_GET = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_GET);
  $_POST = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);   
 }
```

#### Method 2:

```
  foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
        if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
          return addslashes(htmlentities(strip_tags($value),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'));
          } 
          else {
             return htmlentities(strip_tags($value),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
          }
  }
```

I am a bit confused what is the difference between

[`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and [`htlspecialchars()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), and which one i have to use?

which function should be used [`addslashes()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) or [`stripslashes()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) when insert into database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just simply add those symbols to your text, and execute it as SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name VALUES ("Here's my text: ©®");
```

When you want to display it one the website don't do anything with these symbols (but remember to escape at least `<`, `>`, `&` (using [htmlspecialchars()](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)) cause those has special meaning in XML/SGML (HTML) documents)

PS. Also remember to escape text passed to SQL query using [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to avoid any SQL Injection problems. If your server has `magic_quotes_gpc` enabled disable it or at least filter your GET/POST/COOKIE data to its raw value. You should always consciously escape values.

#### EDIT:

According to your comment... I don't remember whether `magic_quotes_gpc` are enabled by default but you can easily undone magic quotes effect. Just on the very beginning of your PHP code add something like this:

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
  array_walk_recursive($_GET, 'stripslashes');
  array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'stripslashes');
  array_walk_recursive($_COOKIE, 'stripslashes');
}
```

Now each GPC value should be always raw - without quotes - so you have to escape it manually before passing any variable into query.

Comment: how do i insert direct input????
i have to insert other fields also, it is not asingle filed in databse

and how do i use this query?? 
`does php latest version add slash by default??`
this is totally rubbish

Comment: should i use `array_walk_recursive()`
or `array_walk()`

Comment: GPC arrays can be multidimensional so you have to use `array_walk_recursive()`.

Answer (score 2):

From the PHP docs for `htmlentities()`:

> This function is identical to
>   htmlspecialchars() in all ways, except
>   with htmlentities(), all characters
>   which have HTML character entity
>   equivalents are translated into these
>   entities.

Don't worry about encoding things when you store them: store the data raw, and then encode it with `htmlentities()` when you display it in your HTML.

Edit: Also, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970880/store-html-entities-in-database-or-convert-when-retrieved).

Answer (score 2):

For starters, you should **just use mysql_real_escape_string when inserting into the database** - this will ensure that whatever you store is safely encoded, yet retains all of the original information.

In terms of output, the key difference between htmlentities and htmlspecialchars is that **htmlentities will convert all characters that have entities** whereas **htmlspecialchars will only convert <, >, &, ", '**

Answer (score -1):

Just use prepared statements.

```
$con = <"Your database connection">;
$input = "What's up? ®, ©, ™";
$stmt = $con->prepare("insert into `tablename` (`field`)values(?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$input);
$stmt->execute();
```