# Difficulties with storing links in a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to store some links in a database but i think my SQL code is off but i cant figure out what the problem is.

```
INSERT INTO `users`(`fbid`, `meme`) VALUES (122321414, http://google.com)
```

I think its the : character but im not sure how to escape it in SQL

If you could post anything to help me then thanks a lot! :D

Thanks Everyone

Comment: Put it in quotes. `'http://google.com'`

Comment: Possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122866/how-to-insert-special-character-in-mysql-via-php-and-display-on-html-page

Answer (score 3):

The string value of the URL has to be in quotes.

```
INSERT INTO `users`(`fbid`, `meme`) VALUES (122321414, 'http://google.com')
```

Comment: You slipped in ahead of me during my mental debate whether to comment or answer...

Comment: Same for both of you.  Got to the submit button just before me :)

Answer (score 3):

Enclose the link in single quotes.  String values must always be quote-enclosed in SQL statements.

```
INSERT INTO `users`(`fbid`, `meme`) VALUES (122321414, 'http://google.com')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not putting the values in quotes

Strings need to be in quotes and number can be in quotes if you want to store as a string

Should be

```
INSERT INTO users(fbid, meme) VALUES (122321414, 'http://google.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the values, when entered into the database.

Use mysql_real_escape_String() to escape such values and **never** forget to enclose the values with a single-quote('), keeps you safe most of the time.

```
$url = mysql_real_escape_string("http://google.com");
$query = "INSERT INTO `users`(`fbid`, `meme`) VALUES (122321414, '$url')";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're having issues with this in the future, make use of mysql_real_escape_string().

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users`(`fbid`, `meme`) VALUES ('122321414', " . mysql_real_escape_string('http://google.com') . ")";
```