# How to fix html string data in PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am saving html data into mysql

like below

```
<p>&lt;div id=&quot;aaa&quot;&gt;asdadad&lt;/div&gt;</p>
<p>&lt;div id=&quot;aaa&quot;&gt;asdadad&lt;/div&gt;</p>
<div class="something">some data</div>
```

when showing the html as string in front end using php , it coverts all 3 lines(above) to html content not just string

But I expect the below result

**first 2 line as string and 3rd line as html**

I used:

```
html_entity_decode($content_from_db, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8');
```

Comment: Are you saying that PHP randomly added `<p>` tags to your string, for no reason?

Comment: possible duplicate [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122866/how-to-insert-special-character-in-mysql-via-php-and-display-on-html-page)

Answer (score 0):

Don't do anything to the data, just print it straight to the browser.  If the data is stored as you say then you will get expected behaviour.  If you don't get expected behaviour then either:

- Data is not stored correctly, view it in MySQL console or a RDBMS
- You are post-processing data after it is being pulled from DB