# How to insert "/" into mysql

Tags: mysql, insert-into

Anyone know how to insert "/" character into a string in mysql. I have a varchar field with 255 space. but when I insert a a string contain "1403/04". it is throwing an error.

**EDIT:** Here is my sql statement, I am using navicat to do the admin

```
INSERT INTO po values(1022,162,10221000339997,'05394906',
  '1403/04 BS BTM102-96 CORE S/SLV PTD TEE',,'',60.00,10.5,25,
  '2014-03-10','2014-03-03')
```

Comment: \......................?

Comment: Can we see your actual query?

Comment: Here is my sql statement, I am using navicat to do the admin

INSERT INTO po values(1022,162,10221000339997,'05394906','1403/04 BS BTM102-96 CORE S/SLV PTD TEE',,'',60.00,10.5,25,'2014-03-10','2014-03-03')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the insert statement you provided in your comment:

```
INSERT INTO po values(1022,162,10221000339997,'05394906','1403/04 BS BTM102-96 CORE S/SLV PTD TEE',,'',60.00,10.5,25,'2014-03-10','2014-03-03')
```

And the error message:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''',60.00,10.5,25,'2014-03-10','2014-03-03')' at line 1
```

The problem is not the string with slashes. The problem is the double commas *after* that string. Either remove a comma, put something in between the two commas, or change your `INSERT` to explicitly list out the columns you are inserting (which you should do anyway, for clarity and to reduce bug potential) and exclude the one that corresponds to the spot between the two commas.

Comment: Thank you so much, you got it. Grate spotting

Answer (score 0):

Try `mysql_real_escape_string()`

`$input="1403/04";`

`INSERT INTO TABLE (table) VALUES ($input)`

**Note:** Mysql is deprecated as of
PHP 5.5 so use mysqli instead.

*I am using cellphone so I will request someone to format my answer*

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am not using PHP. The project is been written in vb6. I have to add more functionality for the product.

Answer (score -1):

Table   Create Table

---

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (                                   
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,         
      `title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,                      
      `body` text,                                           
      `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,                       
      `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,                      
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)                                     
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Now the insert query will work.

```
INSERT INTO posts (title, body) VALUES ("special", "366/88");
                             OR
INSERT INTO posts (title, body) VALUES ('special', '366/88');
```

Both will work.
....................................................................................................................................................................
If you are using PHP
It's better to use  mysql_real_escape_string();

mysql_real_escape_string — Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement

[You should look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122866/how-to-insert-special-character-in-mysql-via-php-and-display-on-html-page)