# Why DOM library remove the escaped special character?

Tags: android, xml

I have this content in XML:

```
<place>
   <placeName>!@#$%&*?/_"'()-+;</placeName>
</place>
```

it's correct when I view Page Source

```
<place>
    <placeName>!@#$%&amp;*?/_&quot;'()-+;</placeName>
</place
```

I use org.w3c.dom.Document, org.w3c.dom.Element, ... to get the content "placeName". The problem is the DOM library remove the escaped special characters. It shows "!@#$%" in Android logcat. Why? How to fix it?

This is a part of my code, I use Node::getNodeValue to get values from the above XML:

```
    public static Document getDocument(final String xml) {
        Document doc = null;
        final DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            try {
            final DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            final InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);

            } catch (final ParserConfigurationException e) {
                System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (final SAXException e) {
                System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
            return doc;
    }

    private static String request() {
        String line = null;
        try {
            final DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            final HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://api-url.com");
            final HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            final HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            line = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        } catch (final MalformedURLException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        } catch (final IOException e) {
            line = "<results status=\"error\"><msg>Can't connect to server</msg></results>";
        }
        return line;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this when you get document from string

```
  dbf.setCoalescing(true);
```

where dbf is

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
```

Comment: It works but could you explain why? I pulled many hairs because of this problem.

Comment: bcz we need to convert cdata node to text node see example http://www.roseindia.net/xml/converting-cdata-nodes-into-text.shtml

Comment: Read it but still don't get it @_@ What's Coalescing?